# Conditional lambda apply across dataframe based on list equality

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` whos columns contain lists of strings

```
df =      A               B 
        ['-1']    , ['0','1','2']
     ['2','4','3'],     ['2']
      ['3','8']   ,    ['-1']
```

I want to get the length of all the lists except the ones that are `['-1']` for the lists that are `['-1']` I want them to be `-1`

Expected output:

```
df = A   B 
    -1,  3
     3,  1
     2, -1
```

I've tried

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len() if not x == ['-1'] else -1)
```

and got the error `('Lengths must match to compare', (132,), (1,))`

I have also tried

```
data_copy[colBeliefs] = data_copy[colBeliefs].apply(lambda x: x.str.len() if '-1' not in x else -1)
```

but this produces the wrong output where `['-1']` becomes `1` rather than `-1`

I'm not sure how I can apply functions to a dataframe based on the whether an entry in a dataframe is equal to a list, or whether an item is in a list.

EDIT: Output of `df.head().to_dict()`

```
{'A': {0: ['-1'],
       1: ['2','4','3'],
       2: ['3','8']},
 'B': {0: ['0','1','2'],
       1: ['2'],
       2: ['-1']}}
```

Comment: please include the output of `df.head().to_dict()` in your question

Comment: @onyambu I have included the output of df.head().to_dict(), or did you want the output of that after `data_copy[colBeliefs] = data_copy[colBeliefs].apply(lambda x: x.str.len() if '-1' not in x else -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: -1 if (ln:=len(x)) == 1 and x[0] == '-1' else ln)

   A  B
0 -1  3
1  3  1
2  2 -1
```

Edit:

If yousing python < 3.8 Use the following:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: -1 if len(x) == 1 and x[0] == '-1' else len(x))
```

Comment: I'm getting
    `df.applymap(lambda x: -1 if (ln:=len(x)) == 1 and x[0] == '-1' else ln)                                                  
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

pointing to `ln:=len(x)`

Comment: @SemicolonExpected The syntax maybe because of the version you are using. do `df.applymap(lambda x: -1 if len(x) == 1 and x[0] == '-1' else len(x))`